# Establish Relationships in Domain Model or ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm beginning to use domain models and viewmodels. My question is, in which of the models do I establish relationships (1-to-many, many-to-many, etc.) between objects? Do I do it in one or the other, or both?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You establish foreign keys (relationships) in your domain models(entities), by use of the virtual keyword.
You can have the same relationships defined in your viewmodels if needed, but without the virtual keyword. Just as long as you realize that your viewmodels won't produce the foreign keys for your models.
If you are going with code-first, you can extend the relationships in the IdentityModels.cs ApplicationDbContext class - OnModelCreating.
When I first dived into this subject, I learned the basics from this website:
[EF6 basics and code-first](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I guess it makes sense to establish relationships in the domain models since they'll be used to create the database and not the viewmodels. Oh, and thanks for the link. :)